# How can i find error in my code for the question for parenthesis matching? (C language)

Tags: c, function, struct, stack, dynamic-memory-allocation

Question is to to check in the character array if the parenthesis is matched or not using stack.

In my code i am not getting any output nor any error so i am unable to find my mistake.

At first i have made a structure for stack.
Then i have made functions to check whether the stack is empty or full to prevent conditions such as stack overflow or underflow.

Then i have made function for parenthesis checker

HERE IS MY CODE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//Initializing the stack with structures

struct stack
{
    int size;
    int top;
    char *arr;
};

//function to check whether stack is empty

int isEmpty(struct stack *ptr)
{

    if (ptr->top == -1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

//function to check whether stack is full

int isFull(struct stack *ptr)
{

    if (ptr->top == (ptr->size - 1))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

//Function for push

void push(struct stack *ptr, char val)
{
    if (isFull(ptr))
    {
        printf("Stack Overflow, Cannot push more elements\n");
    }
    else
    {
        ptr->top++;
        ptr->arr[ptr->top] = val;
    }
}

//Function for pop

char pop(struct stack *ptr)
{
    if (isEmpty(ptr))
    {
        printf("Stack Underflow, Unable to pop elements\n");
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        char val;
        val = ptr->arr[ptr->top];
        ptr->top--;
        return val;
    }
}





//Function for parenthesis matching

int parenthesisChecker(char *exp)
{
    struct stack *st;

    st->size = 100;
    //stack is empty for now
    st->top = -1;
    st->arr = (char *)malloc(st->size * sizeof(char));

    int n_push = 0, n_pop = 0;

    for (int i = 0; exp[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {

        //for open bracket push
        if (exp[i] == '(')
        {
            push(st, '(');
            n_push++;
        }

        //for closed bracket pop
        else if (exp[i] == ')')
        {
            if (isEmpty(st))
            {
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                pop(st);
                n_pop++;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%d times push\n", n_push);
    printf("%d times pop\n", n_pop);

    if (isEmpty(st))
    {

        return 1;
    }
    else
    {

        return 0;
    }
}

int main()
{

    char *c = "akajvd)(()";

    if (parenthesisChecker(c))
    {
        printf("Parenthesis is matched");
        
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Parenthesis is not matched");
        
    }

    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This seems like a good time to learn how to add more warnings when you build, and treat them as errors. But even better time to learn how to use a *debugger* to step through your code statement by statement, while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: On a side-note: When returning from the `main` function, `0` is considered "all is okay and there's no errors or problems", while any small positive non-zero value is considered a "failure" or a problem of some kind.

Comment: As a hint about your problem: You have a pointer variable `st`, but ***where does it point?*** Note that compilers are pretty good at detecting when you use uninitialized variables. It would definitely be able to in this case. So if the compiler doesn't warn you about it already, then you should definitely enable more warnings.

Comment: By enabling compiler warnings: *uninitialized local variable `st` used*

Comment: I have enabled the compiler warning but still the situation is same.

Comment: Should i declare st in the main function and then use it in the parenthesis checker and also create the stack in main function instead of parenthesisChecker function?

Comment: Enabling compiler warnings does not fix the bug: it only shows where it is. You must assign a value to `st` before you can validly use its value. But, was `struct stack *st;` meant to be `struct stack st;`? (And then use `.` instead of `->`, and pass its address to the helper functions).

Answer (score 0):

The pointer `st` within the function `parenthesisChecker` is not initialized and has an indeterminate value

```
struct stack *st;
```

So dereferencing the pointer like for example in this statement

```
st->size = 100;
```

invokes undefined behavior.

Also the function produces a memory leak because it does not free the memory allocated for the data member `arr` of the structure `struct stack`.

The function parameter should have the qualifier `const` because the passed string is not being changed within the function.

```
int parenthesisChecker( const char *exp );
```

And such functions as `pop` and `push` should not output any message. It is the caller of the functions that decides whether to output a message.

I would write the program the following way.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct stack
{
    size_t size;
    size_t top;
    char *arr;
};

struct stack make_stack( size_t size )
{
    struct stack st = { .size = size, .top = 0, .arr = malloc( size ) };
    
    if ( st.arr == NULL ) st.size = 0;
    
    return st;
}

void free_stack( struct stack *st )
{
    free( st->arr );
    st->size = 0;
    st->top = 0;
}

int isEmpty( const struct stack *st )
{
    return st->top == 0;
}

int isFull( const struct stack *st )
{
    return st->top == st->size;
}

int push( struct stack *st, char val )
{
    int success = !isFull( st );
    
    if ( success )
    {
        st->arr[st->top++] = val;
    }
    
    return success;
}

int pop( struct stack *st, char *val )
{
    int success = !isEmpty( st );
    
    if ( success )
    {
        *val = st->arr[--st->top];
    }
    
    return success;
}

int parenthesisChecker( const char *s )
{
    int success = 1;
    
    if ( *s != '\0' )
    {
        struct stack st = make_stack( strlen( s ) );
    
        success = st.size != 0;
    
        for ( ; success && *s; ++s )
        {
            if ( *s == '(' )
            {
                success = push( &st, *s );
            }
            else if ( *s == ')' )
            {
                char c;
                success = pop( &st, &c );
            }
        }
    
        success = success && isEmpty( &st );
    
        free_stack( &st );
    }       
    
    return success;
}

int main(void) 
{
    const char *s = "akajvd)(()";

    if ( parenthesisChecker( s ) )
    {
        puts( "Parentheses are matched" );
    }
    else
    {
        puts( "Parentheses are not matched" );
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Parentheses are not matched
```